# split comma separated string to array using bash script

Tags: bash, unix

Why does the values not get set in the array[@] and subsequently $i. **This question has been asked before and I am aware of that** , the reason I am asking here is because it doesn't work. **Before you jump to mark this as duplicate**, please can you let me know why it doesn't work? Not sure what is wrong here.

```
#!/bin/bash

DEALS=1739719, 1714630, 1733697, 1723940, 1666257, 1665239, 1674778, 1720875, 1674777, 1763086, 1735526, 1845881

IFS=', ' read -ra array <<< "$DEALS"

for i in ${array[@]}
do
        echo $i
done
```

Comment: It doesn't work because your line `DEALS=1739719, 1714630, 1733697,...` isn't an assignment at all. It runs a *command* called `1714630,` with the first argument `1733697,` and the variable `DEALS=1739719,` temporarily set in the environment.

Comment: I need 2 more pairs of eyes !

Comment: Beyond that, `${array[@]}` has all the bugs of `${array[*]}`; it needs to be quoted, `"${array[@]}"`, to be accurate. Similarly, `echo $i` should be `echo "$i"`

Comment: ...anyhow, if you want to actually have `DEALS=...` be an assignment, quote the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to realise that I have to assign with quotes!